# Pelican Error: No module named typogrify.filters

Tags: python, pelican

I'm publishing a blog using Pelican and, for some reason, the same command that worked 2 months ago throws the following error:

> ERROR: Could not process md/artigo 4 - teste.md
>     | ImportError: No module named typogrify.filters

I'm using the following commands to publish on github pages:

```
make github
```

And this command throws the same error:

```
pelican content -o output -s pelicanconf.py
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either install Typogrify via:

```
pip install typogrify
```

... or turn it off via the following line in your settings file:

```
TYPOGRIFY = False
```